# Error while validating epub in epubcheck, it says this

Tags: epub, epub3

> Error while parsing file: element "ruby" not allowed anywhere;
>   expected the element end-tag, text or element "a", "abbr", "acronym",
>   "applet", "b", "bdo", "big", "br", "cite", "code", "del", "dfn", "em",
>   "i", "iframe", "img", "ins", "kbd", "map", "noscript", "ns:svg",
>   "object", "q", "samp", "script", "small", "span", "strong", "sub",
>   "sup", "tt" or "var" (with xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

and the code where it is pointing this error looks like this

```
<p>i don't want this<ruby>Artifact<rt>Variable Drag-Ride</rt></ruby>.</p>
```

can you tell me why this error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Ruby tags should be supported in epub3 (search for "ruby" in [this reference](http://www.uvm.edu/~choman/ebooks/EPUB%203%20Best%20Practices.pdf)) but here the element is probably inside a tag where it's not allowed (xhtml is very strict).

Search for the sentence and look for the previous tags, they may have some restrictions resulting in this error on epubcheck.